# How to give automatically top space to navigation bar in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController`. I am designing the screen for iPhone 5s. I have a `UIImageView` & I am giving top space to container of 20. I also have `UINavigationBar` at top.So the space given of 20 is not enough. `UIImageView` is hidden behind the `UINavigationBar`. I can resolve this issue by giving much space from top. But in that case at design time my `UI` will not look proper. So is there any way by which space from `UINavigationBar` is automatically calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Attribute Inspector` set `Top Bar` to `Translucent Navigation Bar` like this

[image]

then set `Top Space` of imageView to `Top Layout Guide` like,

[image]

Comment: why you are not set navigation type as Opaque Navigation Bar ? means if we set this type then we don't need to manage other views constraint. if I'm not wrong. If I wrong can you please give me some more idea about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

set navigation bar type as opaque Navigation Bar so it will opaque that much space from your view controller and show your view content after navigation bar space they will not hide inside of navigation bar.

but if you set navigation bar type as Translucent Navigation bar then your content will hide inside of navigation bar so set "Opaque Navigation Bar" type. no need to do any other stuff for that.

I hope it will help you!